# Debugging with the Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, golang

I am currently working on https://yfirbord.com
I've just started playing around with the GrovePi and I wonder: what's the fastest way to write code on my mac, compile it for the RaspberryPi, ship it there, and run it? That would be for debugging, mainly.
Also, I heard about PlatformIO, is it something that can make this process easier?

Comment: The RPi is really no different than any other linux development environment. Top choices are usually something like git, ftp, or sftp.

Comment: True story, I think I will automate something via ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's also resin.io which offers a "playout" system that handles updates, etc. when dealing with a fleet of Raspberry Pis.

Comment: Good one, this looks great.